# Why was my question moved, and why was it then deleted off of the original site?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked a question a while ago on Super User: https://serverfault.com/questions/227152/what-is-a-good-os-to-mess-around-with-xen-dom0

I logged into Super User today to find it had been moved. I don't see anything server-specific about the question however. And what is more troubling is that I can not even see who closed the question because the original question on Super User has been deleted (which I didn't think was possible, and I definitely don't think is a good idea).

So why was my question moved, and more worrying, why was the original question deleted?

Comment: As an aside: clicking on "migrated from superuser.com" redirects you [to the original](http://superuser.com/questions/127002/what-is-a-good-os-to-mess-around-with-xen-dom0?noredirect=1) with a `?noredirect=1` URL. But maybe you indeed cannot see that, despite it being your own question?

Comment: @Arjan. that is an interesting point. Can we see our own deleted questions? From here it appears not

Comment: Okay, @Earlz, then apparently you must have 10k rep [to see](http://i.imgur.com/eWlYZ.png) your own deleted question. (Though I'm sure you can see your own deleted answers.)

Comment: if you know the URL, you might be able to see [the revision history](http://superuser.com/posts/127002/revisions)?

Answer (score 5):

There is a process that automatically deletes migration stubs after 30 days. Since we auto-redirect on deletion to the target site, the migration stubs are of no lasting value on the source site.

Comment: Except for its (public) revision history maybe? (Not a problem for me.)

Comment: This question [was deleted after 3 days](http://superuser.com/questions/127002/what-is-a-good-os-to-mess-around-with-xen-dom0?noredirect=1), not 30. Though: it was indeed asked more than 30 days ago.

Comment: That explains why I couldn't figure out who deleted it. It felt automated.

Answer (score 2):

Typically virtualization questions belong on serverfault, especially concerning Xen as it's so frequently used in server environments.  In other words, Xen professionals are more likely to be on and help out at serverfault than on superuser.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Any idea why the original question was deleted from superuser?

Comment: @Earlz I did the original migration, however the system is not showing me who deleted it. From what I see it was deleted by yourself, however I will raise the question with the developers.

Comment: Could we then change the FAQ, please? [It states](http://serverfault.com/faq): *Server Fault is for system administrators and desktop support professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity.*